# NSComboBoxCell subclass example?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscombobox

I have been working on a custom UI for my Cocoa application.
By looking around the internet, I have managed to learn how to subclass a large number of UI objects on MacOSX. In many cases I could make the appearance work the way I want.

The last UI element that I am working on, is `NSComboBoxCell`. It appears to be a `NSTextFieldCell` with an `NSButtonCell` attached. The part that I want to override is the `NSButtonCell` that I believe is drawing the "Arrow Button". Has anyone done this before, and if so, what method is used, so that I can change its appearance?

Are there any ways to know where to draw the `NSButtonCell`?
(Can I override and install my own `NSButtonCell`?)

Thanks!

Comment: From the cocoa-dev mailing list:

_James Walker wrote:

In my NSComboBoxCell subclass, I figured out where the "button" part ought to be as follows:_

`NSRect drawingRect = [self drawingRectForBounds: cellFrame];
NSRect titleBounds = [self titleRectForBounds: drawingRect];
NSRect buttonBounds = NSMakeRect( NSMaxX( titleBounds ),
 NSMinY(drawingRect),
 NSMaxX(drawingRect) - NSMaxX( titleBounds ),
 NSHeight(drawingRect) );`

_And then I drew my own button content._

This seems to work for me. Thanks James!

Answer (score 0):

From the cocoa-dev mailing list:

James Walker wrote:
In my NSComboBoxCell subclass, I figured out where the "button" part ought to be as follows:

```
NSRect drawingRect = [self drawingRectForBounds: cellFrame];
NSRect titleBounds = [self titleRectForBounds: drawingRect];
NSRect buttonBounds = NSMakeRect( NSMaxX( titleBounds ), NSMinY(drawingRect), NSMaxX(drawingRect) - NSMaxX( titleBounds ), NSHeight(drawingRect) );
```

And then I drew my own button content. This seems to work for me.

Thanks James!